# Compiler claims that variable is ambiguous, will not run

Tags: c++, arrays

My compiler (VS 2015) claims that the line "int rents[size]" contains size, which is ambiguous and will not run the program.

I have made countless modifications and cannot achieve a version that will at least accept the variable size as something that is not ambiguous. I'm not all that experienced with the extreme details of c++ and would like some guidance as to why I am receiving this error. Thanks!

errors in console:

```
    1>c:\users\**\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\arrays and pointers\arrays and pointers\source.cpp(9): error C2872: 'size': ambiguous symbol
1>  c:\users\**\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\arrays and pointers\arrays and pointers\source.cpp(8): note: could be 'const int size'
1>  c:\users\**\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\arrays and pointers\arrays and pointers\source.cpp(9): note: or       'size'
```

code below

```
    #include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <cstdio>

using namespace std;

const int size = 6;
int rents[size];

void sortArray(int *rents, const int size);

int main()
{

    bool run_again = true;
    // Define Numbers
    int num0;
    int num1;
    int num2;

    //Define Pointers
    int *ptrnum0;
    int *ptrnum1;
    int *ptrnum2;

    // Set Pointers
    ptrnum0 = &num0;
    ptrnum1 = &num1;
    ptrnum2 = &num2;



    int choice;

    do
    {

        cout << "Main Menu:\n";
        cout << "1.) Display Numbers\n";
        cout << "2.) Display First and Last Rent Locations.\n";
        cin >> choice;

        if (choice == 1)
        {

            while (run_again)
            {
                int num;
                cout << "Int 0: ";
                cin >> num0;
                cout << endl;
                cout << "Int 1: ";
                cin >> num1;
                cout << endl;
                cout << "Int 2: ";
                cin >> num2;
                cout << endl;
                run_again = false;
            }



            cout << "num0 == " << num0 << endl;
            cout << "num1 == " << num1 << endl;
            cout << "num2 == " << num2 << endl << endl;

            cout << "&Numbers: Addresses: \n\n";

            cout << "&num0 == " << &num0 << endl;
            cout << "&num1 == " << &num0 << endl;
            cout << "&num2 == " << &num0 << endl << endl;

            cout << "*ptrnum0 == " << ptrnum0 << endl;
            cout << "*ptrnum1 == " << ptrnum1 << endl;
            cout << "*ptrnum2 == " << ptrnum2 << endl << endl;

            // Sort Entered numbers
        }

        // SHow First and last
        if (choice == 2)
        {


        }


        system("pause");
        return 0;

    } while (choice < 3);
}




void sortArray(int *rents, const int size) {

    bool swap;
    int temp;
    int count = 0;

    do
    {
        swap = false;
        for (count = 0; count < (size - 1); count++) {
            if (*(rents + count) < *(rents + count + 1))
            {
                temp = rents[count];
                *(rents + count) = rents[count + 1];
                *(rents + count + 1) = temp;
                swap = true;
            }
        }
    } while (swap);

    for (count = 0; count < size; count++)
        cout << *(rents + count) << " ";
    cout << "\n";

}
```

Comment: Although some compilers accept sizes of arrays from const variables, it is fundamentally wrong and in this case is confusing the compiler. Avoid using variables as size of c-arrays. This is job for macro typically,, or for `constexpr` nowadays. `#define SIZE  6 \\ 
int rents[SIZE];`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You declared a constant named 'size'  and as a parameter named 'size'.

Change to something like:

```
const int RentsMaxSize = 6;
int rents[RentsMaxSize];
```

[Reading the error message explains this]

Also, please be aware that arrays are zero based in C++

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue I just changed the name of the variable size to size_1 and it got resolved.Do try it.`int size_1 = 0`